# find element in sorted array without using for or while

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, search

I  have an array in which seven numbers are sorted from the smallest to the biggest. I have to write a recursive function that returns the index of a specific value. I am not allowed to use while or for loops. I have absolutely no approach and do not know how to solve this. Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: a binary search

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is sorted, the question probably wants you to use binary search rather than a linear search approach. Look up "recursive binary search". It should help you with your problem.

Sample code from http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/algorithms/searching/rbinarysearch.html:

```
int rBinarySearch(int sortedArray[], int first, int last, int key) {
// function:
//   Searches sortedArray[first]..sortedArray[last] for key.  
// returns: index of the matching element if it finds key, 
//         otherwise  -(index where it could be inserted)-1.
// parameters:
//   sortedArray in  array of sorted (ascending) values.
//   first, last in  lower and upper subscript bounds
//   key         in  value to search for.
// returns:
//   index of key, or -insertion_position -1 
//                 if key is not in the array.

    if (first <= last) {
       int mid = (first + last) / 2;  // compute mid point.
       if (key == sortedArray[mid]) 
           return mid;   // found it.
       else if (key < sortedArray[mid]) 
           // Call ourself for the lower part of the array
           return rBinarySearch(sortedArray, first, mid-1, key);
       else
           // Call ourself for the upper part of the array
           return rBinarySearch(sortedArray, mid+1, last, key);
    }
    return -(first + 1);    // failed to find key
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  the problem is I am only allowed to give three things to the function: the sorted array. the value that is looked for and the size of the array. That make`s this task very complicated

Comment: @ArthurJohnson, in that case, I think this thread may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392637/recursive-binary-search-method-having-only-2-arguments it is in java, but the logic should be easily transferable.

Comment: *That make`s this task very complicated* -- It really doesn't.  The first argument could be the pointer to a sorted sequence of values -- it doesn't matter if the pointer is in the middle of the original sorted array, the beginning of the original sorted array, etc -- it's just a pointer to a series of sorted values.  The issue with this answer is that each recursive call always passes the beginning of the original array each time.  Just change that deficiency, and you basically have the answer.

Comment: Thank You Paul, but what do you mean with  recursive call always passes the beginning of the original array each time. How can I make the function start with another place in the array with each call

Comment: `int rBinarySearch(int sortedArray[], int first, int last, int key)` -- That declaration is exactly the same thing as `int rBinarySearch(int* sortedArray, int first, int last, int key)`.  Those `[]` on the first parameter does *not* mean it is an array -- that is actually an `int *`.  Given that, the next two parameters denoting the first and last need to be changed to reflect the new fact that `someArray` is always pointing to the first element of a "shorter" array.

Comment: @ArthurJohnson Look at it conceptually -- on each iteration, half of the original array is "thrown away" -- there is no need (as in the answer's code is doing) of passing a pointer to the entire array each and every time, since half of it is discarded and not part of the search.  So just pass the beginning of the part of the array that is still being used in the search, and throw away the `first` and `last` parameters and replace with the appropriate `size` parameter.  Doing this satisfies all of the requirements you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the function signature:

```
int search(int *sorted, int value, unsigned size)
```

We first test if `size` is 1, as that's our *base case*.  If `size` is one, we check that one element, `sorted[0]`, to see if it equals the `value` we're looking for.   If it does, `return 0`, the (only) index.  If it doesn't `return -1` to indicate "not found".

If `size` is greater than one, we continue on.  First we calculate `half` which is `size / 2`.  Then we call ourselves recursively with that diminished size:

```
result = search(sorted, value, half);
```

if this `result` isn't -1 , return it as it's the index we want.  If `result` is -1, we continue on.  We again call ourselves recursively but this time with the other half of the array we didn't test earlier:

```
result = search(sorted + half, value, size - half);
```

if `result` is not -1, then we return `result` **plus** the `half` size.  If `result` is -1, then simply `return -1` as the value isn't in the array.